# push notifications are not received in my android device from gcm?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi In my project I added gcm notification services and followed developers official page.I sent device registration id to server my key also saved in server.And my server sends notification to gcm server  at that time server i get success message .But i didn't get any push notifications to my device.Please provide any suggestions. Thanks in advance

and in my logcat showing this message

```
GCMBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
GCMBroadcastReceiver: GCM IntentService class: com.example.GCMIntentService
GCMBaseIntentService: Acquiring wakelock

this is my manifest with all other permissions

 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
             <category android:name="com.example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>       
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: show code what u tried.

Comment: Send your code or which devices you are trying.. Simply you can cross check Settings-> Application Manager -> Your app -> check box with Show notification (on Android 4.1 & higher)

Comment: Also check your device has valid google account ie. register with google play store.

Comment: i followed http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: post your manifest file...

Comment: In what package is your `GCMIntentService`? Is it in `com.example`?

Comment: GCMIntent service in com.<domainname>

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem of receiving push messages, even though GCM server replies "Success", because of wifi privacy. When I used my company wifi, I coudn't receive message in mobile, since they were blocked GCM server port . So, even your wifi also could be a one of the reason. check it once { this answer is for others , who may face this}

Answer (score 0):

can you please check in your device did you login in gmail account?

if you are not logged in you will not get push notification.

first login in gmail then then try may be it will work.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have GCMIntentService.class in main package to receive broadcast from GCM server
(prefer any thing related to GCM be in main package) 
i hope this work